# What's the best way to open up a list with 0 or 1 options?

Tags: scala

In Scala I have a `List` with an optional `Option`. This arises for example when you use `for` comprehension on a `List` and your yield returns an `Option`. In my case I was processing a JSON object and using `for` comprehension on the list of fields (`List[JField]`).

What's the best way to open up the list and map `List()` to `None` and `List(Some(a))` to `Some(a)`?

A first approach would be

```
def headOrNone[A](list:List[Option[A]]) = 
    list match {
        case Nil => None
        case a::Nil => a
    }
```

Another approach

```
def headOrNone[A](list:List[Option[A]]) = list.headOption.getOrElse(None)
```

A third approach (a variation on the headOption implementation)

```
def headOrNone[A](list:List[Option[A]]) = if (list.isEmpty) None else list.head
```

I personally prefer the third approach. Is there a better name for this function than `headOrNone` and what is the idiomatic scala way to write it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
def headOrNone[A](list: List[Option[A]]) = list.flatten.headOption

headOrNone(List(Some(4)))   // Some(4)
headOrNone(List())          // None
```

Though the first choice has the advantage of giving you an error if you happen to have list with more than one item, which, according to your description, seems like an error condition.

But personally, I would re-evaluate the code that produces the `List[Option[A]]` and see if there's a way to just have it return the right thing in the first place!

Comment: The third option is a variation on the headOption implementation and as such it seems the most efficient. Why do you prefer the second?

Comment: Nice flatten.headOption, out and then back in the Option :) I will try to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 6):

You're solving a problem that probably shouldn't have been created.  Instead, you probably want

```
for (x <- list) yield f(x)  // Yields Option
```

to be

```
list.flatMap(f)
```

and then you'll have either zero or one things in your list to begin with (which you can extract using `headOption`).